# CSS: Position: Absolute Right without horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a demo of this layout here: http://jsfiddle.net/LwRva/

What I'm trying to achieve is a layout that is 680px wide for most users, but only 480px - **without a horizontal scrollbar** for those using a smaller resolution. (Imagine 680px is actually 1180px, and 480px is 980px - just for using this in JSFiddle.)

It's essentially a 3-column div layout, where the left and right columns are hidden if the page can't fit them on.

I already have the left column working exactly as I want it to, it doesn't alter the horizontal scrollbar if it doesn't fit on the page. My problem is with the right column. Due to the fact that a negative margin-right doesn't work in the same way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a quick suggestion: Have you considered CSS3 Media Queries? It's probably much easier: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RoToRa is correct for the media. A possible css for your layout could be the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {.featured-box-left {display:none} }
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.featured-box-left,.featured-box-right{display:none;}
}
```

When the screen's width is 580px then hide `.featured-box-left`. If the Screen is 480px or lower then hide both left and right.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LwRva/6/

Generally what you are trying tou achieve is call [Responsive Web Design](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=Responsive+Web+Design&cp=21&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=Responsive+Web+Design&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&fp=eda1291fdd569703). A List Apart has a great article you can find informative: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Genius! Thanks so much guys. I haven't used these Media Queries before, but they are super useful. Thanks!